# CSS Multiple selection based on parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

For the below code:

```
<div id="main">
   <div class="one"></div>
   <div class="two"></div>
   <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

I want to select all of the 3 divs inside by class name and parent like this:

```
div#main div.one div.two div.three{/*apply common properties for all 3*/}
```

^ Doesn't work.

This is an abstract example so I need a solution similar to the one above, things like:

```
div#main>div{/*apply common properties for all 3*/}
```

Would not work in the real-case scenario.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you have any other choice than this syntax :

```
div#main div.one,
div#main div.two,
div#main div.three
{/*apply common properties for all 3*/}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about that, but I was hoping for a shorthand if any. In the real-case example, I have more than 3 divs.

Comment: +1 for interesting question, I have already thought about that, but found nothing :(

Comment: Hm, ok. Thank you for your answer. My problem was that besides having a few more divs, the "path" to them is like: div#main div.something div.anotherThing div.one/two/three. Oh well, I'll just do it the long way. Thanks again.

Comment: Dear *Francisc from the Past*, don't use long, over-qualified selectors. Trust me.

Comment: I asked me the same question but related to the common ancestor. Didn't think that css path syntax would be so inflexible. Thought that it would support it with something like: `div[class=col3] [h1, p]` where `h1` and `p` would be descendants of `div` with attribute `class="col3"`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for because the example is fairly abstract, however, you could try to give each of the child divs a second class after their numbering and selecting by that. This assumes you have control over the server-side/html generation. For example:

```
<div id="main>
    <div class="one other-style"></div>
    <div class="two other-style"></div>
    <div class="three other-style"></div>
</div>

div#main div.other-style {
    font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
}
```

Except don't actually use Comic Sans.

This answer may be a bit simplistic, but without knowing a bit more that's all I could think of!

Comment: whoops, I guess I necro'd this one. Sorry, forgot to check asked date before I answered. Maybe this will help someone in the future

Comment: No worries. It's good advice. I can't remember the project I was working on back then, but what you are suggesting is what I usually use in such cases. Thanks.